# if(!data) block is entered even if data is null

Tags: javascript

I am facing very strange problem for me, the if block is entered even when data is null. I have tried with `if(data !== null)`.

```
const data = await this.redis.getDataByKey(ITEMS_KEY);
if (!data) {
      console.log("data will be displayed");
      console.log(data);
      console.log("data was displayed");
      data.push(...itemsForInsert);
    }
```

The output is:

```
data will be displayed
null
data was displayed
```

Sorry if my error is trivial, but I was struggling a lot.

Comment: `!data` should be `data` if you want a truthy value. `data !== null` should work when data should be non null

Comment: with ```data !== null``` it still enters the if block and prints the data as null

Answer (score 2):

It should. `if` expects a boolean. `null` is implicitly converted to `false`, and `!false` is `true`.

Comment: Still enters the block
```if (current) {
      console.log("data will be displayed");
      console.log(current);
      console.log("data was displayed");
      current.push(...itemsForInsert);
    }```

Answer (score 0):

`!data` should be `data` if you want a truthy value (a non null value). `data !== null` should work when data should be non null. Please provide a full example where it doesn't work for you.

```js
const data = null
if (data !== null) {
  console.log("data will be displayed");
  console.log(data);
  console.log("data was displayed");
}
if (data) {
  console.log("data will be displayed");
  console.log(data);
  console.log("data was displayed");
}
if (!data) {
  console.log("data is null:");
  console.log(data);
}
```

The only thing i can think of right now, is that `data` isn't actually `null` but has a overwritten toString.

```
class B {
  toString() {
    return 'null'
  }
}

const a = null
const b = new B()

console.log(`${a}`, !!a) // null false
console.log(`${b}`, !!b) // null true
```

Comment: @AntoniDobrenov Can you use a debugger instead of console.log to test if data is really null. I can't reproduce it with your example :)